# Query performance differs with just date change in where clause

Tags: sql-server, where-clause, response-time

I have this SQL

```
SELECT 
    ABS(a.cantidad - ISNULL(b.cantidad, 0)) as cantidad, 
    a.codarticulo, a.codalmacen, a.codarticulotallaje 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         ABS(ISNULL(SUM(cantidad), 0)) AS cantidad, 
         movimientos.codarticulo, codalmacen, 
         movimientos.codarticulotallaje 
     FROM movimientos 
     WHERE 
         (fecha > '12/02/2015') AND (fecha < '12/05/2015 10:29:30') 
         AND (altabaja = 2) AND 
         ((tipodocumento = 3) OR (tipodocumento = 4)) AND (codalmacen = '3') 
     GROUP BY 
         movimientos.codarticulo, movimientos.codalmacen, 
         movimientos.codarticulotallaje) as a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT 
        ABS(ISNULL(SUM(cantidad),0)) as cantidad, 
        movimientos.codarticulo, codalmacen, codarticulotallaje 
    FROM movimientos 
    WHERE (fecha > '12/02/2015') AND (fecha < '12/05/2015 10:29:30') 
      AND (codalmacen = '3') AND (altabaja = 1) 
      AND ((tipodocumento = 5) OR (tipodocumento = 6)) 
      AND (cantidad > 0) 
   GROUP BY 
       movimientos.codarticulo, 
       codalmacen, codarticulotallaje ) as b 
       on a.codarticulo = b.codarticulo AND 
          a.codarticulotallaje = b.codarticulotallaje
```

The date time is `dd/MM/yyyy` format the table movimientos have around 450000 rows.

If my date is less than 12/02/2015 in both `WHERE (fecha > 12/02/2015)` queries. Or over 05/05/2015 the query takes from 200 ms to 2 secs to answer which is ok.

However if the date is like in the example it takes over a min to answer.

I personally do not know what the reason could be.

Comment: The server obviosuly decides for a different execution plan. Compare the two. Is column 'fecha' indexed? I'm guessing not, you have to create an index for this column.

Comment: Yes that was the reason.

Comment: @Zitu your problem resolved by Marko comment, if so then let me know

Comment: yes it was resolved that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, as a rule of thumb, such difference means that SQL Server is selecting different execution plan for every set of criteria. And (again as a rule of thumb) this means that it doesn't have a good index to start with (or there are no indexes at all).
Start with examining execution plans, look for table scans. Those are bad.
And the most obvious choice: it seems there's no index for column `fetcha`. Create it and you'll see the difference.

.